Postgres fails post-installation step on Windows 10 for version 16.3 of PostgreSQL
I have downloaded the executable installer for PostgreSQL.  When I double-click on the executable, it would have me run the installer as an administrator.
For most of the installation it goes smoothly, but then in the postinstallation step I get the message:
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
 The database cluster initialisation failed.

Upon looking at the logs, the message I get is:
running bootstrap script ... Execution of PostgreSQL by a user with administrative permissions is not
permitted.
The server must be started under an unprivileged user ID to prevent
possible system security compromises.  See the documentation for
more information on how to properly start the server.
child process exited with exit code 1

It appears that I have to start the server, not as an administrator, but I have to run the install as an administrator.  Because of this, the entire installation rolls back.  How would I bypass this message?  The error in the log makes sense, but I don't know how to comply.  Is there a multi-stage process I could use to install this and then to start the server?
